# Can two or more different parent Categories have the same Subcategory in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, categories

I hope this is the right place to post this question!

My site deals with Real Estate. Sometimes I will want to post on the topic ECONOMY, which can be a Subcategory of the Category NEWS; but it is also appropriate as a Subcategory of the parent Category VALUE, since the Economy affects Real Estate Values!

Am I thinking about WordPress clearly here?

Can two or more different parent Categories have the same Subcategory?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes in that they can both have a sub-category called **News**, but no in that they will be separate terms. Unfortunately objects in WP can only have one parent.

Comment: Also, while the good folks here will usually help if they can, your best bet for WordPress specific questions is to use the [WordPress Development Stack Excange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).